# Why do you have to count after 'select *' on MySQL?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

So, today I tried doing the following:

```
SELECT count(users), * FROM table;
```

And it gave me a syntax error on the `,` after `count(users)`, but this:

```
SELECT *, count(users) FROM TABLE;
```

Or this:

```
SELECT count(users), users FROM table;
```

Does work. Is there a reason for that?

---

**Edit**: Per request, here's the error:

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* from mygamedb' at line 1

MySQL Workbench  underlines the comma after the `count(*)`. I'd like to point out I know it's an ugly select, I should group by and such, but the question is not about how to make it work, but a short example asking about *why* does that happen, not how to make it work.

Comment: None of these are valid SQL.  They should all fail because the additional columns in the `select` are not in a `group by` clause.

Comment: @GordonLinoff MySQL extension, valid but ugly and depends on MySQL global variable settings `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`

Comment: @scaisEdge Just see my demo

Comment: @scaisEdge `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*`

Comment: @GordonLinoff My question is not about how to do it, but how or why does that happen!

Comment: @scaisEdge Added the error and further explanation

Comment: @scaisEdge 5.7.14

Comment: What _is_ there to explain? They implemented it that way, and documented it accordingly. So this isn’t an actual programming question IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

You  could use alias to make it work:

```
SELECT count(users), t.* 
FROM table t;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=5b25de9523700284b81ecc0d8ea357a1)**

```
SELECT count(users), *
FROM table;
-- You have an error in your SQL syntax;
-- check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
-- syntax to use near '* FROM tablez' at line 1
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work without an alias, or if you don't put the count after selecting everything (`*`)?

Comment: @Newwt **Probably parsing thing**. **[Oracle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=67ade341a12a90d37c40dede9771eb19)** is even more strict.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to explain you when you will use this `SELECT count(users), * FROM table;`  query then mysql query fetch table as like
Table :

```
---count(users)---
result of count
```

Then you are adding * means fetch all attribute value but now mysql check * from fetch table but that is not their because table has only one attribute that name is count(users) that's why it show error. but when you will use t.table (t is alias of table) that fetch from table and it works fine.

I am commenting here what is my understanding.

Thanks